# Binding beyond the DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a DataTemplate for templating my ItemsControl's items which are TimeSheet's Details.
I have  couple of TextBox representing certain values of my TimeSheet's Details but their IsEnabled property depends on the TimeSheet itself, not the details.

```
<ItemsControl 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TimeSheet.TimeSheetDetails}"
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TimeSheetDetail}"
/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="TimeSheetDetail">
   <TextBox
      Text="{Binding Houre}"
      IsEnabled="Binding ??????">
</DataTemplate>
```

Since the IsEnabled property cant be found in the TimeSheetDetails but can be found in my ViewModel, i would like to bind directly to my ViewModel's Property but when i try binding, to my ViewModel from my DataTemplate, it only seems to look in my TimeSheetDetail.

How can i access my ViewModel's public property directly?

Comment: I had same problem check this out :
  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814020/silverlight-databinding-error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to your parent's `DataContext`:

```
{Binding DataContext.IsEnabled, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}
```

Comment: Ty alot, really usefull but you made a small mistake, its more like IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" because TimeSheet alredy is the DataContext.